# File reading error in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get word by word from files and add each first to a dictionary and then all as a list to document, but I started to have this error

```
File files[] = directory.listFiles();
ArrayList<String> tockenList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (File f : files) {

    Scanner s = null;

    int DocID = Integer.parseInt(f.getName().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
    try {
        s = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter("[ ,!?. ]+");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Doc doc = new Doc();
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        tockenList.add(s.next());
        String str = s.next();  // this line is 34
        Dictionary.getInstance().addElementToListOfTerms(str, DocID);
    }
    doc.addListOfTokens(DocID, tockenList);
    s.close();
```

everything work good while debugging and no error is shown, but when running it gives this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at TeamLab.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Thanks guys, I got already. it should be like this

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
            String str = s.next();
            tockenList.add(str);        
            Dictionary.getInstance().addElementToListOfTerms(str, DocID);
        }
```

Comment: Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of a prior try block should be inside that try block. At present you are continuing after a `FileNotFoundException ` as though it hadn't happened.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you swap these lines

```
   tockenList.add(s.next());
    String str = s.next();  // this line is 34
```

to be

```
    String str = s.next();  
    tockenList.add(str);
```

as you are testing for `hasNext` but then reading twice

Comment: Actually the first file is empty so while loop is not entered first time. But it worked good before.

Comment: Maybe clean your projects and re-compile as your answer doesn't make sense.  if the the `while` loop is not entered, then how can line 34 cause the error?  Refresh your question with the code you are using